# listview and round corner doesn't work

Tags: android

What I want:
 I'am using a Listview and I want to use this view with round corners.

Situation:
A listview without round corners :-( .

I use different examples to define a customShape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

If I apply this customShape to the listview items(Textview) every entry in Listview have round corners. It is crazy!!! So the  customShape.xml works but not with the border of the listview.

Any idea???

regard marcel

Comment: set this drwable as background of your listview not its item

Comment: What you describe is exactly what should be happening... your list view items are using the rounded corner shape thus EACH list view item will have rounded corners. I think you might want to modify the actual ListView instead. Maybe even use a 9patch drawable ;)

Comment: hey..if u r trying to show the listview with rounded corner u can show it inside a dialog box...i am showing a list view inside the dialog box and it open with rounded corner.....its jst an idea...:)

Comment: I'am realy sry (to make myself not clear enough!) The reason to apply the shape to the items was only for testing(that nothing is wrong). I want round corners at the borders of the listview(not the items). I already set the background in XML and via Code like ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
l1.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.customshape);  Sry. my english is not my mother tongue...

Answer (score 1):

Get view by id for the list view.
ListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_shape);

Remove the background settings in the xml .
Put the custom_shape.xml in drawable folder. Remove the stroke component from it as it is not needed to round the corners